# How to make the UI respond to subscriptions in Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, subscriptions, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using `react-apollo` as a client to communicate with a GraphQL server that I created. I managed to successfully get subscriptions working with the `data.subscribeToMore()` function as detailed in the [Apollo documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/subscriptions.html) and the up-to-date data shows up when I run my web application inside of two windows. What I'm trying to do is make it so that an notification alert gets displayed when another client changes data that I'm currently looking at so that I can tell that something changed in case I wasn't paying attention? What would be the correct way of doing this?

- `update` method?
- `updateQueries` method?

The `dataFromObjectId` and `refetchQueries` fields did not seem relevant for what I was trying to do. Since I'm using redux, is there a way I could dispatch actions directly from my subscription? Would notification alerts be something that I have to use `client.subscribe()` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest version of Apollo, you should be handing the component a prop named "updateQuery" that contains logic for handling the data.

http://dev.apollodata.com/react/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more

This section goes over what you need to do, but essentially your "updateQuery" function should do the following:

1. Take in an object of structure `argumentName.data` which contains the new information.
2. Adds the new object to the results by creating a new object.
3. Returns the new results object.

so it might look something like this:

```
(prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
  if (!subscription.data) {
    //If no new data, return old results
    return prev;
  }
  var newResults = Object.assign(
    {},
    prev,
    queryName: { [subscriptionData.data, ...prev[queryName]] }
 );
 return newResults;
```

Comment: There was no other way I was able to get it to work under 1.x